# Balanced payment integration with PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, balanced-payments

I  am using balanced payment for transferring payment with my site but having problem with it and I am using PHP Curl code in my programming language, But I have not received any type oh hopeful response of my problem.

My Curl code is written as below.

```
$url = "https://api.balancedpayments.com/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP1K1dZWDLVf3nIfthUpaROF/";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&amount=5000&description=Some descriptive text for the debit in the dashboard');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

This "key" is hidden buy security reason.

If anyone has a solution to my problem so please contact me my email is ishansourabhjain@hotmail.com.

Thanks & Regards,
Ishan S. Jain

Comment: What response do you get, and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Alex you should contact via email (-:

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your issue has to do with trying to POST your key instead of supplying it in basic auth format.

Also, note you're building your code against an old API version (1.0). 1.1 is recommended.

Why not use the existing Balanced client library for PHP? https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php

Comment: Actually I can't understand some keyword like use and other httpful. 
So can you please let me know step by step configuration or installation of this script because there is a composer and phar, not getting how to install..

Comment: Sure, a walkthrough is given in the quickstart guide in their documentation. https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/guides/quickstart/setup/?language=php

This information is also contained in the repository's README. https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/README.md